# Returning multiple variables with pandas.series.apply

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply a single function to a dataframe column.  This function returns multiple results which I want to go to multiple columns in the original dataframe. I cant seem to get around the "too many values to unpack" error....

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': [1,2,3,4]})

   x
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
```

The function I want to apply :

```
def do_math(x):
    double = 2*x
    triple = 3*x
    return double, triple
```

My attempt to apply it (which doesnt work):

```
df['DOUBLE'], df['TRIPLE'] = df['x'].apply(do_math)
```

What I want :

```
   x  DOUBLE  TRIPLE
0  1       2       3
1  2       4       6
2  3       6       9
3  4       8      12
```

Comment: As an aside, this example shouldn't be done with `apply`. `df['DOUBLE'] = df['x'] * 2`, etc... is the better option. I assume this is just a toy example, so we shouldn't be so pendantic, but generally when doing `apply` its only there for cases where regular pandas ops don't do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the result of `Series.apply` to list then assign to multiple columns

```py
df[['DOUBLE', 'TRIPLE']] = df['x'].apply(do_math).tolist()
```

```
print(df)

   x  DOUBLE  TRIPLE
0  1       2       3
1  2       4       6
2  3       6       9
3  4       8      12
```

You can also try `DataFrame.apply` on rows with `result_type='expand'`

```py
df[['DOUBLE', 'TRIPLE']] = df.apply(lambda row: do_math(row['x']), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

```
print(df)

   x  DOUBLE  TRIPLE
0  1       2       3
1  2       4       6
2  3       6       9
3  4       8      12
```

Since your operation is simple, you can also try [`df.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html)

```py
df = df.eval('''
double = 2 * x
triple = 3 * x
'''
)
```

```
print(df)

   x  double  triple
0  1       2       3
1  2       4       6
2  3       6       9
3  4       8      12
```

Answer (score 1):

You could change `apply` to return a `Series`:

```
def do_math(x):
    double = 2*x
    triple = 3*x
    return pd.Series([double, triple])

df[['DOUBLE', 'TRIPLE']] = df.apply(lambda row: do_math(row['x']), axis=1)

   x  DOUBLE  TRIPLE
0  1       2       3
1  2       4       6
2  3       6       9
3  4       8      12
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing them separately:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': [1,2,3,4]})
df['DOUBLE'] = df['x'].apply(lambda x: 2*x)
df['TRIPLE'] = df['x'].apply(lambda x: 3*x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.transform` when all the functions you want are defined separately.

```
def double(x):
    return x * 2

def triple(x):
    return x * 3

df[['DOUBLE', 'TRIPLE']] = df['x'].transform([double, triple])
```

This can take any number of functions you want. You can add more functions when needed and won't have to modify other functions.