# Extracting City and State from a column in CSV using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-science

```
917 1st St, Dallas, TX 75001
682 Chestnut St, Boston, MA 02215
669 Spruce St, Los Angeles, CA 90001
669 Spruce St, Los Angeles, CA 90001
```

**so, i'm trying to extract the city and state from the given data...**

```
def get_city_state(address):
    asplit = address.split(",")
    ssplit = address.split(" ")
    city = asplit[1].split()[-1]
    state = asplit[2].split()[0]
    return city , state


all_data['City'] = all_data['Purchase Address'].apply(lambda x: f"{get_city_state(x)}")
all_data.head()
```

Comment: What's the problem? If you want to return multiple values in apply, you can look at [Returning multiple variables with pandas.series.apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176826/returning-multiple-variables-with-pandas-series-apply).

Comment: Maybe you want `all_data[['City', 'State']] = all_data['Purchase Address'].apply(get_city_state).tolist()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you want this ?

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame({'Purchase Address': ['917 1st St, Dallas, TX 75001',
                               '682 Chestnut St, Boston, MA 02215',
                               '669 Spruce St, Los Angeles, CA 90001',
                               '669 Spruce St, Los Angeles, CA 90001']})
```

Just the city :

```
def get_city_state(address):
    asplit = address.split(",")
    ssplit = address.split(" ")
    city = asplit[1].split()[-1]
    state = asplit[2].split()[0]
    return city 


all_data['City'] = all_data['Purchase Address'].apply(get_city_state).to_list()
```

Just the States :

```
def get_city_state(address):
        asplit = address.split(",")
        ssplit = address.split(" ")
        city = asplit[1].split()[-1]
        state = asplit[2].split()[0]
        return states 
    
    
    all_data['States'] = all_data['Purchase Address'].apply(get_city_state).to_list()
```

Both :

```
def get_city_state(address):
    asplit = address.split(",")
    ssplit = address.split(" ")
    city = asplit[1].split()[-1]
    state = asplit[2].split()[0]
    return city , state


all_data[['City', 'State']] = all_data['Purchase Address'].apply(get_city_state).to_list()
```

Output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using Pandas. I suppose that you have tha data ina csv file or you can edit them to a csv file. Then:

1º Import pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
```

2º Create a dataframe with your data (it can be csv, jason, xls, ...). In this case code refers a comma separated csv file:

```
pd.read_csv('path or url of csv file', sep = ',')
```

Output: Prints your dataframe
After thar, you can edit the line and assign to a var:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path or url of csv file', sep = ',')
```

Now, to extract the columns you need:

```
df(['City','State'])
```

Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but it doesn’t answer the question. Instead, **vote up** the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a more constructive way – by contributing your own answers to questions your peers have asked here.