# How to extract values from column to another two?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I use Pandas first time.
There is a regex rule that extract mm, yy from string `0122` or `012022` or `01/22`:

```
def extractMMYY(str):
    pattern = r"^((?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|[0-9])[.\/\\-]*([0-9]{3}[0-9]|[0-9]{2})$"
    match = re.search(pattern, str)
    mm = None
    yy = None

    if match:
        mm = match.group(1)
        yy = match.group(2)

        if mm and yy:
            return mm, yy
    return mm, yy
```

I have tried to apply this function for specific column and get a new dataframe:

```
df_filtered = df[df['column_name'].apply(extractMMYY)];
```

As result I need to create a two additional columns: MM, YY with values from `extractMMYY`.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_name': {0: '0122', 1: '012022', 2: '01/22', 3: '9922', 4: '03/23'}})

df_filtered = pd.DataFrame(df['column_name'].apply(extractMMYY).tolist(), columns=['MM', 'YY'])
```

```
print(df_filtered)

     MM    YY
0    01    22
1    01  2022
2    01    22
3  None  None
4    03    23
```

Comment: Thank you I will, if mm empty it still creates a new column mm?

Comment: @Oliver Yes, make sure you always return two values in `extractMMYY` method.

Comment: I got this error:

`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:`

Comment: @Oliver Could you provide the sample data that causes the error? I couldn't reproduce this error with mm and yy both are `None`

Comment: Column with name "column_name" has 03/23 value

Comment: @Oliver I updated the answer and couldn't reproduce the error.

Comment: @Oliver Yes, your `extractMMYY` method uses `re.match`

Comment: I have column with name "1" when I try to use it:

----> 1 df_filtered = pd.DataFrame(df['1'].apply(extrac..
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

Comment: df.columns give me: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], dtype='int64')

Comment: I got it should be int 1 instead string, thank you a lot! Do you know how to filter inital dataset by new data set by mm field?

Comment: Is it possible to add columns mm, yy to current dataset?

Comment: @Oliver To add it into current dataset, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176826/returning-multiple-variables-with-pandas-series-apply/72176901#72176901.